# equivalent of an ExecutorService in D language?

Tags: java, d

The D documentation is a bit difficult to understand, how do I achieve the following Java code in D?

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(num_threads);

for (File f : files) {
    service.execute(() -> process(f));
}

service.shutdown();
try {
    service.awaitTermination(24, TimeUnit.HOURS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Would I use std.parallelism or std.concurrency or is this functionality not available in the standard library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you posted is best represented by `std.parallelism`. You can use the `parallel` helper function in there, which when used in a foreach it will automatically execute the body of the foreach loop in a thread pool with a thread number (worker size) of `totalCPUs - 1`. You can change this default value by setting `defaultPoolThreads = x;` before doing any parallel code (best done at the start of your main) or by using a custom taskPool.

basically then your code would translate to this:

```
foreach (f; files.parallel) {
    process(f); // or just paste what should be done with f in here if it matters
}
```

std.parallelism is the high-level implementation of multithreading. If you want to just have a task pool you can create a `new TaskPool()` (with number of workers as optional argument) and then do the same as above using `service.parallel(files)`.

Alternatively you could queue lots of tasks using

```
foreach (f; files) {
    service.put!process(f);
}
service.finish(true); // true = blocking
// you could also do false here in a while true loop with sleeps to implement a timeout
```

which would then allow to implement a timeout.

Though I would recommend using parallel because it handles the code above for you + gives each thread a storage to access the local stack so you can use it just the same as a normal non-parallel foreach loop.

A side-note/explanation on the documentation:

The `std.concurrency` is also very useful, though not what you would use with your example. In it there is  a  spawn function which is spawning a new thread with the powerful messaging API. With the messaging API (send and receive) you can implement thread-safe value passing between threads without using sockets, files or other workarounds.

When you have a task (thread with messaging API) and call `receive` in it it will wait until the passed timeout is done or another thread calls the `send` function on the task. For example you could have a file loading queue task which always waits using receive and when e.g. the UI puts a file into the loading queue (just by calling send once or more) it can work on these files and send them back to the UI task which receives using a timeout in the main loop.

`std.concurrency` also has a `FiberScheduler` which can be used to do thread style programming in a single thread. For example if you have a UI which does drawing and input handling and all sorts of things it can then in the main loop on every tick call the FiberScheduler and all the currently running tasks will continue where they last stopped (by calling `yield`). This is useful when you have like an image generator which takes long to generate, but you don't want to block the UI for too long so you call `yield()` every iteration or so to halt the execution of the generator and do one step of the main loop.

When fibers aren't running they can even be passed around threads so you can have a thread pool from std.parallelism and a custom FiberScheduler implementation and do load balancing which could be useful in a web server for example.

If you want to create Fibers without a FiberScheduler and call them raw (and check their finish states and remove them from any custom scheduler implementation) you can inherit the `Fiber` class from `core.thread`, which works exactly the same as a Thread, you just need to call Fiber.yield() every time you wait or think you are in a CPU intensive section.

Though because most APIs aren't made for Fibers they will block and make Fibers seem kind of useless, so you definitely want to use some API which uses Fibers there. For example vibe.d has lots of fiber based functions, but a custom std.concurrency implementation so you need to look out for that.

But just to come back to your question, a `TaskPool` or in your particular case the `parallel` function is what you need.

https://dlang.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html#.parallel
https://dlang.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html#.TaskPool.parallel

Comment: "When fibers aren't running they can even be passed around threads"
Where I can find about this? I thought that fibers couldn't be passed to others threads.

Comment: @Patric https://dlang.org/phobos/core_thread.html#.Fiber "Rather, fibers may be freely passed between threads so long as they are not currently executing."